# Rails 5 app running background tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, mixpanel

I've built a small rails app and have a ruby script that I would like to run in the background of my app. Currently this code is placed in my lib directory (lib/tweetstreamer.rb). What's the easiest way to accomplish this task while having the code continue to run in the background? Would I need to use some type of command inside my application controller? I found that when I use "rails runner path/to/tweetstreamer.rb" my script runs perfectly.

tweetstreamer.rb can be seen below

```
require 'tweetstream'
require 'twitter'
require 'mixpanel-ruby'

  TweetStream.configure do |conf|
  conf.consumer_key = "XXXXXXX"
  conf.consumer_secret = "XXXXXXX"
  conf.oauth_token = "XXXXXXX"
  conf.oauth_token_secret = "XXXXXXX"
  conf.auth_method = :oauth
  end

  @store_account = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key = "XXXXXXX"
  config.consumer_secret = "XXXXXXX"
  config.access_token = "XXXXXXX"
  config.access_token_secret = "XXXXXXX"
  end

  client = TweetStream::Client.new

  client.track('mysampletweet') do |status|

  msg = status.text
  tag = "#mysampletweet"

  puts msg
  puts tag

  if msg.include? tag
  message = "@#{status.user.screen_name} Happy Holidays from @myaccountname!"
  sleep 5
  @store_account.update(message, in_reply_to_status_id: status.id)
  end

  @tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new("XXXXXXX")

  @tracker.track(status.id, 'Tweets Received', { 'Hashtag' => tag, 'Message' => msg })

  puts 'Your code ran'
  end
```

Comment: The answer on this depends on your production server configuration.  But essentially it would involve delegating it to a separate process and having it run alongside your main app.  One way to do this would be to put this into a rake task and then call that task to boot a separate process.

Comment: This code should run periodically or it should be triggered from the main app?

Comment: @OleksandrAvoyants this should be triggered from the main app.

Comment: @Twhitt06 Is it on all the time, or triggered only periodically from within the main app (e.g. every hour, every time a new user signs up, etc.).

Comment: @Kelseydh ideally I'd like to have it running all the time. For more context (may or may not be helpful), the app has no UI, it's mainly an API that controls several events. I'm just stuck on keeping this script running.

Comment: @Twhitt06 If it runs all the time, then the rake task will work.  Just have it boot with the rest of your processes when your app starts.  But first step here is to make sure this works when manually triggered.  Then for deployment you can think about how to get them booted simultaneously. Depending on your production configuration that could be from using a `Procfile` (e.g. if its hosted on Heroku) which you can run locally in development via one command on your command line using something like Foreman:  https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

Comment: @Kelseydh I've tested the rake task and it works. I came up with possibly an ugly solution that runs the code. Inside my application controller I created a new thread and used %x[bundle exec rake myappname:tweetstreamer]. Does what I need for right now. Thank you so much for the guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make this a rake task.  Change the namespace myappname to the name of your app.

Save this in *myappname/lib/tasks/tweetstream.rake*:

```
namespace :myappname do
  task :tweetstream => :environment do

    require 'tweetstream'
    require 'twitter'
    require 'mixpanel-ruby'

    TweetStream.configure do |conf|
    conf.consumer_key = "XXXXXXX"
    conf.consumer_secret = "XXXXXXX"
    conf.oauth_token = "XXXXXXX"
    conf.oauth_token_secret = "XXXXXXX"
    conf.auth_method = :oauth
    end

    @store_account = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key = "XXXXXXX"
    config.consumer_secret = "XXXXXXX"
    config.access_token = "XXXXXXX"
    config.access_token_secret = "XXXXXXX"
    end

    client = TweetStream::Client.new

    client.track('mysampletweet') do |status|

    msg = status.text
    tag = "#mysampletweet"

    puts msg
    puts tag

    if msg.include? tag
    message = "@#{status.user.screen_name} Happy Holidays from @myaccountname!"
    sleep 5
    @store_account.update(message, in_reply_to_status_id: status.id)
    end

    @tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new("XXXXXXX")

    @tracker.track(status.id, 'Tweets Received', { 'Hashtag' => tag, 'Message' => msg })

    puts 'Your code ran'
    end
  end
end
```

Then to boot in a separate process, from your command line you can run it with `bundle exec rake myappname:tweetstream`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm new to rails, how would I go about booting the rake task from within my app?

Comment: I updated the answer to show where you could save this file.  To run from the command line you execute with `rake myappname:tweetstream`, with `myappname` in all places being replaced with the name of your rails app.  When you set up a separate process for production, you can either call this rake task once or call it periodically if you have a scheduler process.

Comment: Ah I didn't see you want to trigger this from within your app.  Another approach would be to make it a service object within your app, which you can then call from within your app to trigger a separate process to handle it using DelayedJob, Sidekiq or Resque.